# Query AdventureWorks 2019

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables:

- `production.product`
- `sales.salesorderdetail`

In the AdventureWorks 2019 sample database.

Write a report that displays the most expensive item from each invoice along with its amount

```
Invoice number, product title, product amount
```

Comment: Need a lot more information, what query have you try already? What DBMS are you using? We don't even know the field names.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

- Build a CTE (Common Table Expression) to list the orders, details, and products
- Create a row number - based on `ROW_NUMBER()` function - to find the most expensive product
- Select from that CTE and show only the most expensive product per order

I used this code (your column names aren't always accurate and don't always exist - I tried to guess as best I could. Adapt if needed):

```
WITH BaseData AS
(
    SELECT
        soh.SalesOrderNumber,
        ProductName = p.Name,
        sod.OrderQty,
        p.ListPrice,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY soh.SalesOrderID ORDER BY p.ListPrice DESC)
    FROM 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh 
    INNER JOIN
        Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod ON sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
    INNER JOIN 
        Production.Product p ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
)
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    BaseData
WHERE
    RowNum = 1
ORDER BY
    SalesOrderNumber;
```

and I get an output something like this (only first few rows):

| SalesOrderNumber | ProductName | OrderQty | ListPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SO43659 | Mountain-100 Silver, 44 | 2 | 3399.99 |
| SO43660 | Road-450 Red, 52 | 1 | 1457.99 |
| SO43661 | Mountain-100 Silver, 44 | 2 | 3399.99 |
| SO43662 | Road-150 Red, 62 | 1 | 3578.27 |
| SO43663 | Road-650 Red, 60 | 1 | 782.99 |